# Laravel: order by relationship (product sorted by first order date)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have `products` and `orders`. For a `product` I can get the `orders` and also get the first `order` (using recently added [ofMany](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many)):

```
public function orders() {
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class)
}

public function firstOrder() {
    return $this->hasOne(Order::class)
        ->ofMany('created_at', 'min');
}
```

I can get `products` with recent first `orders`, but I'm not sure how to order the `products` by that `date`:

```php
Product::whereHas('firstOrder', fn($q) => $q->where('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(7)))
    ->with('firstOrder')
    // ->orderBy('firstOrder.created_at') 
    // orderBy fails: The multi-part identifier "firstOrder.created_at" could not be bound.
```

How can I get the `products` ordered by first order date that have a recent (e.g. last week) first `order` as part of the database query (so: no `->get()->sortBy(...)`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not easy out of the box.

One way is to use a [subquery join](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#subquery-joins) (you can move the date condition to the subquery)

```
$firstOrders = DB::table('orders')
    ->select('product_id', DB::raw('MIN(created_at) as first_order_created_at'))
    ->where('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(7))
    ->groupBy('product_id');

$products = Product::with('firstOrder')
    ->joinSub($firstOrders, 'first_orders', function ($join) {
            $join->on('products.id', '=', 'first_orders.product_id');
        })
    ->orderBy('first_orders.first_order_created_at', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Hope it gives you at least a lead to what you're trying to do.